# PowerShell 5 Copy-Item not working

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to copy all .pdf files from all folders and sub folder (dirs. and subdirs).

```
Folder1
  1.pdf
  2.pdf
Folder1\Foder2\3.pdf
Folder1\Folder2\4.pdf
Folder1\Foder2\Folder3\5.pdf
Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\6.pdf
```

First I used

```
 $source = "c:\Folder1\"
 $desti = "D:\foderA\"
 PS> Get-ChildItem -recurse $source -Filter "*.pdf"
```

It displays all the files in dir and sub dir but when I try to use copy-Item I get the error.

```
 PS> Get-ChildItem -recurse $source -Filter "*.pdf" | % {Copy-Item $_    -destination $desti}
```

Error: Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Folder1\Folder2.... because it does not exist. Error points to source being non-existent. 
What am I doing wrong?
Is it because I have read only on the source drive\Folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output objects from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Copy-Item` (i.e., you don't need `%` [which is an alias for `ForEach-Object`]); e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter "*.pdf" -File | Copy-Item -Destination $desti
```

The `-File` parameter restricts the search only to files.

Comment: May be add -file in gci (if directory contain .pdf) ;)

Comment: Works with or without %

Comment: @BharatPatel that may be, but not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it right, `$_` is only grabbing the filename, so you lose the path and it tries to use the path your running the script from.  Use this instead which will keep the full path.

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter "*.pdf" | % {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $desti}`

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -Recurse C:\path\to\search\*.pdf C:\path\to\output\copies
```